# Can a 3 phase IGBT based front end converter work without line reactor?

Tags: active-filter, igbt

I have been working on developing a 3 phase active power filter, which has a 3 phase IGBT bidirectional converter. I have been able to develop APFC (Active Power Filter Converter) with the line reactor. However, when I remove the line reactor, and run the converter under open loop and only as a PWM rectifier, my incoming ac current shoots up which forces me to force trip my ac supply. Can anybody tell me if it is possible to run the converter without the line reactor?[image: This is the schematic for APFC I am using.]

Comment: Do you have a schematic to show?

Comment: It is possible.... But you need to increase the switching frequency to rediculous levels. Inductance is needed, that is key to this topology. The inductance of the supply is viable if what I stated above is met

Answer (score 2):

You have a rectifier charging a smoothing capacitor. It can only do so when the DC line voltage is higher than the residual capacitor voltage.

- The charging only ever happens when the DC line voltage peaks.

And this means you get needle-shaped currents when the line voltage peaks and no current the other times. The line reactor smoothes those current peaks.

Remove both the capacitor and the line reactor. It's a 6-pulse rectifier, you don't need a capacitor anyways.